# Standard ASP.NET API template running on docker doesn't show any page

Tags: .net, docker

### Steps I follow.

1. Clone [this](https://github.com/m-azyoksul/AspDotNetApiWithDockerSample) repo. It is the default ASP.NET API template. (Weather forecast)
2. Open CMD on the solution directory.
3. Run `docker build -t webapp4 -f WebApplication4/Dockerfile .`
4. Run `docker run -d -p 5000:80 webapp4`
5. Navigate to `http://localhost:5000/swagger`. Output: This localhost page can’t be found (HTTP ERROR 404)
6. Navigate to `https://localhost:5000/swagger`. Output: This site can’t provide a secure connection (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

alternatively

4. Run `docker run -d -p 5000:443 webapp4`
5. Navigate to `http://localhost:5000/swagger`. Output: This page isn’t working (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
6. Navigate to `https://localhost:5000/swagger`. Output: This site can’t be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)

I try to run the same project using VS code plugin, VS plugin, and Rider plugin. None of them opened the swagger page.

When I create a new project on VS 2022 with Docker and run it without changing anything, the window that automatically opens also doesn't show the swagger page.

When I run `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`, it works perfectly. I cannot see any problems on Docker Desktop either.

I am somewhat new to this and I am in the complete dark here. What could be wrong?

### Edit

More information:

[image]

[image]

Logs

```
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","address":"https://[::]:443","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Development","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Development","envName":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app/","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app/","contentRoot":"/app/","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

`https://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast` also doesn't work. Running directly on Kestrel or IIS just works fine.

Comment: Seems the Swagger UI is only created if the environment is set to Development. Have you set the environment to Development? As a quick test, you could comment out that code and run it again and see what happens.

Comment: @mason I see what you mean but the problem is not that. I added more information to the post.

Comment: You've shown some logs...but only a portion of them. Include them as *text*, not as images.

Comment: @mason I am sorry about that. Fixed it now.

Comment: What do you get at http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast when you bind 5000:80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no certificate in the image, so https won't work. You've tried running the image in a lot of different ways, so it's unclear to me which run the logs you show are from.

Anyway, the issue is that you need to be in development mode to use Swagger. Set it using an `-e` option

```
docker run -d -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -p 5000:80 webapp4
```

Then you can go to http://localhost:5000/swagger and try out the API

If you prefer, you can add

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
```

to the Dockerfile for a more permanent solution, like this

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj", "WebApplication4/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication4"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

Comment: You are absolutely right and a lifesaver. It never occurred to me to check "/weatherforecast" on HTTP which was working the whole time. I understand why the env variable is important for swagger as well. Now I need to figure out how to add SSL certificate to my image.